# Angular custom directive issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I created a custom directive which has a chart and another div.
On mouse hover on my chart I need to hide show that div.

```
<div id="chart">

    <div id="extraDetails" ng-show="showpreview">
        <p>Show some list</p>       
    </div>

</div>


 module.directive('d3Heatmap',  function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                scope: {
                    showpreview: "="
                },

  templateUrl:'heatMapTemplate.html',

                link:function(scope,element, attrs){
}}); code here
```

On mouseover and out, i change the value of showpreview. But the div extraDetails does not hide or show up. Will appreciate any inputs.

Comment: Where are you setting show preview? It looks look it may be an issue of you setting showpreview on a parent scope instead of you isolated scope.

Comment: Am setting show preview in the link function. On mouse over am setting it to true, and on mouse out event am setting it to false.An new with angular framework. So not sure what is the right way to achieve this.

Comment: .on("mouseover", function(d) {

                                if(node.depth>0)return;
                                var ancestors = getAncestors(d);
                                $scope.showPreview="true";                         
                            })
                            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                          
                                $scope.showPreview="false";})